Physical meaning of Entanglement Entropy
For a quantum system $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ with two subsystems $A$ and $B$ and with the total density matrix $\rho$, we can define the Entanglement Entropy] for $A,B$ respectively as (where $\rho_A,\rho_B$ are the reduced density matrices from $\rho$)
$$
S_A=-\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_A \ln\rho_A)
\quad
S_B=-\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_B \ln\rho_B) \quad .
$$
This is what I learnt from Wiki, but I'm not clear with the Physical Meaning
of such a definition.
Intuitively, I would expect the entanglment entropy to detect how strong the two subsystems $A,B$ are correlated. For example, for any two observables $O_A,O_B$ which live within subsystems $A,B$ respectively, we can detect their correlation perhaps by their connected correlator
$$
\langle O_A\otimes O_B\rangle_c=\langle O_A\otimes O_B\rangle - \langle O_A\rangle_A\cdot\langle O_B\rangle_B \quad ,
$$
which can be written more explictly as
$$
\langle O_A\otimes O_B\rangle_c=\mathrm{Tr}((O_A\otimes O_B)\rho)-\mathrm{Tr}(O_A\rho_A)\mathrm{Tr}(O_B\rho_B) \quad .
$$
And of course for $S_A=S_B=0$, which means $\rho=\rho_A\otimes\rho_B$, the connected correlation $\langle O_A\otimes O_B\rangle_c=0$, so I wonder for general $S_A,S_B\neq 0$, whether we get an inequality or other stuff to restrict the value of things such as the connected correlator $\langle O_A\otimes O_B\rangle_c$?

I think it should be emphasized that Entanglement entropy is a measure of entanglement for pure joint states, but it's not good to measure entanglement in general bipartite states.
Consider the state $\rho = \frac {1}{d^2} \mathrm I\otimes \mathrm I$. If we look for the reduced density matrices, they are $\rho_A = \rho_B = \frac 1d \mathrm I$, i.e., the same reduced matrices that you could get from the maximally entangled state $|\Psi\rangle = {1\over \sqrt d} \sum_{k=1}^d |kk\rangle$. For both we have maximal entanglement entropy $S_A$ or $S_B$, but the first is separable and the second one maximally entangled.
This is the reason that such measure are not directed connected with correlation: there are uncorrelated states with such entropy.
However, there are two reasons for keep using such measure, and one of these reasons are connected with correlations.
The first reason is that pure states are uncorrelated with anything else. It can be easily proved that if the reduced density matrix of any of the parties, say Alice, is a pure state, it should be uncorrelated with Bob, implying that there is no correlation between them. So "local mixedness" of $\rho_A$ gives us a necessary (but not sufficient) condition of correlation (I'm using the word correlation instead of entanglement, because Alice and Bob could share a classically correlated state).
The second reason is that Entanglement Entropy is based on a more robust entropic property of entanglement known as Nielsen and Kempe criteria.
In Classical probability theory, when we have a classical random variable, we can calculate its entropy $S(A)$. If we consider two random variables $A,B$, we can calculate its joint entropy $S(A,B)$. It can be proved that
$$
S(A,B) - S(A) \geq 0
$$
In words, if we consider one more random variable, the entropy only increase. So The global disorder is always greater than any local disorder.
In quantum theory, it can be proved that for separable states (please, check it in Horodecki X4 paper section V for a detailed review and references) a similar property holds:
$$
S(\rho_{AB}^{sep})-S(\rho_A) \geq 0
$$
Where the entropy above is the von Neumann entropy. For entangled states, this is not always true anymore, and the most straightforward example is the case when we have a pure joint entangled state, whose global entropy is zero and any nonzero entropy for its reduced states are a violation of the equation above.

This is far from trivial. In the Horodecki's article, they say in introduction

In fact, a fundamental nonclassical aspect of entanglement was recognized in 1935. Inspired by the EPR paper, Schrödinger analyzed some physical consequences
of quantum formalism and he noticed that the twoparticle EPR state does not allow individual states to be
ascribed to the subsystems, implying “entanglement of
predictions” for the subsystems. Then he concluded:
“Thus one disposes provisionally  until the entanglement is resolved by actual observation of only a common description of the two in that space of higher dimension. This is the reason that knowledge of the
individual systems can decline to the scantiest, even to
zero, while that of the combined system remains continually maximal. The best possible knowledge of a
whole does not include the best possible knowledge of
its parts—and this is what keeps coming back to haunt
us” .This curious aspect of entanglement was long unintelligible, as it was related to the notion of “knowledge” in
the quantum context. Only in the second half of the
1990s was it formalized in terms of entropic inequalities
based on the von Neumann entropy  Violation of these inequalities by entangled states is a signature of entanglement of quantum
states; however, the physical meaning of this was unclear.

So despite that Schrodinger was aware about similar property, it took a long time to connect the von Neumann entropy with some more operational meaning. In the V section of the article, they say

This new “nonintuitive” property of compound quantum systems, intimately connected with entanglement,
was a long-standing puzzle from both a physical and a
mathematical point of view. The main difficulty was that,
in contrast the concept of correlation, which has a clear
operational meaning, the concept of information in
quantum theory was obscure until 1995, when Schumacher showed that the von Neumann entropy has the operational interpretation of the number of qubits needed to transmit quantum states emitted by a statistical source.


I think if you want to have more intuition about entropic properties of entanglement, you should avoid to think about correlations. Take a look in these references and learn more about von Neumann entropy.

As already stressed in the other answer, the von Neumann entropy of the reduced density matrix is a measure of entanglement for pure bipartite states.
More specifically, what can be proven is the following: Given two bipartite states $\lvert\phi\rangle_{AB}$ and  $\lvert\psi\rangle_{AB}$, two parties Alice (A) and Bob (B) can convert $N$ copies of  $\lvert\phi\rangle_{AB}$ into  $M$ copies of $\lvert\psi\rangle_{AB}$ for $N,M\to\infty$ in an (asymptotically) reversible fashion,
$$
\lvert\phi\rangle_{AB}^{\otimes N} \quad\longleftrightarrow\quad\lvert\psi\rangle_{AB}^{\otimes M}\ ,
$$
precisely if
$$
\frac{N}{M} = \frac{E(\psi)}{E(\phi)},
$$
or $NE(\phi) = ME(\psi)$
[where $E(\chi) = S(\mathrm{tr}_B\lvert\chi\rangle\langle\chi\rvert)$ ],
i.e., the von Neumann entropy $E(\chi)$ precisely quantifies the amount of entanglement per copy  in this asymptotic setting.
(Note that this is in close analogy how the Shannon entropy quantifies the amount of information. For a proof of this fact, you can e.g. refer to the book of Nielsen and Chuang.)
